# Meeting request timing mismatch with full VS lite outlook version

Tags: java, outlook, icalendar, outlook-web-app

I am creating meeting request with java code and sending it to full as well as lite version of outlook as shown below:

```
final SimpleDateFormat iCalendarDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd'T'HHmm'00'");
                final long uid =System.currentTimeMillis();
                iCalendarDateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(MRBSConstants.TIMEZONE));
final String calendarContent = "BEGIN:VCALENDAR\n"
                                            + "METHOD:REQUEST\n"
                                            + "PRODID: BCP - Meeting\n"
                                            + "VERSION:2.0\n"
                                            + "BEGIN:VEVENT\n"
                                            + "DTSTAMP:"+ iCalendarDateFormat.format(meetingEndTime) + "\n"
                                            + "DTSTART:" + iCalendarDateFormat.format(meetingStartTime) + "\n"
                                            + "DTEND:"+ iCalendarDateFormat.format(meetingEndTime) + "\n"
                                            + "SUMMARY:test request\n"
                                            + "UID:" + uid + "\n"
                                            + "ATTENDEE;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;PARTSTAT=NEEDS-ACTION;RSVP=TRUE:MAILTO:" + Arrays.toString(recipetList) + "\n"
                                            + "ORGANIZER:MAILTO:" + from+ "\n"
                                            + "LOCATION:" +loc + "\n"
                                            + "DESCRIPTION:" + body+ "\n"
                                            + "SEQUENCE:0\n" + "PRIORITY:5\n" + "CLASS:PUBLIC\n" + "STATUS:CONFIRMED\n" + "TRANSP:OPAQUE\n" + "BEGIN:VALARM\n"
                                            + "ACTION:DISPLAY\n" + "DESCRIPTION:REMINDER\n" + "TRIGGER;RELATED=START:-PT00H15M00S\n" + "END:VALARM\n" + "END:VEVENT\n" + "END:VCALENDAR";
```

And it is working fine with lite version of outlook means it giving correct time in lite version but in full version of outlook it showing different timings.?why

Here **MRBSConstants.TIMEZONE** value is **GMT-5:30**.

I have also tried adding **VTIMEZONE COMPONENT** but in that case outlook cant recognize the ics file as correct.

Do we have any general ics object which can work on both version?

Comment: is there a pattern in the offsets? like 2 hrs always or 3 hrs always etc., this can help narrow down the possibilities.

Comment: thank you for your response no offset were there.

Comment: you mentioned in your question that outlook is `"showing different timings"`, what did you mean by that?

Comment: if the meeting is set for 3 to 3:45PM then in lite version its showing meeting request 3 to 3:45 PM but in ful version it showing different timing like 4:15 to 5 PM

Comment: something might be wrong with the timezone setting.. please review that, also post the generated VCARD.

Comment: Sorry for late reply:

Comment: http://pastebin.com/xDhY7ae1 here is my vcard